# php case文で書き換え

Tags: php, laravel

下記コードをcase文を使って書きたいです。

```
return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.変数.name');
```

みたいな感じにして書けるのかなと予想しているのですが、うまくできません。
ご教授ください。

```
$age = $this->employee_age;
if ($age >= 20 && $age < 30) {
    return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.1.name');
} elseif ($age >= 30 && $age < 40) {
    return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.2.name');
} elseif ($age >= 40 && $age < 50) {
    return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.3.name');
} elseif ($age >= 50 && $age < 60) {
    return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.4.name');
} elseif ($age >= 60 && $age < 70) {
    return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.5.name');
} elseif ($age >= 70) {
    return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.6.name');
} else {
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP: switch](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/control-structures.switch.php)

> もっと複雑な比較を行うには、`true` を `switch`文の値として指定するやり方が使えます。

```php
$age = $this->employee_age;
switch (true) {
    case $age >= 20 && $age < 30:
        return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.1.name');
    case $age >= 30 && $age < 40:
        return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.2.name');
    case $age >= 40 && $age < 50:
        return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.3.name');
    case $age >= 50 && $age < 60:
        return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.4.name');
    case $age >= 60 && $age < 70:
        return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.5.name');
    case $age >= 70:
        return config('apps.flags.employee_generations.6.name');
    default:
        return "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

    class Sample{

        public $employee_age ;

        function config($param){ return $param ; }

        function Check(){
            $age = $this->employee_age;

            switch(true){
                case $age >= 70 : $ch = 6       ; break ;
                case $age >= 60 : $ch = 5       ; break ;
                case $age >= 50 : $ch = 4       ; break ;
                case $age >= 40 : $ch = 3       ; break ;
                case $age >= 30 : $ch = 2       ; break ;
                case $age >= 20 : $ch = 1       ; break ;
                default         : $ch = FALSE   ; break ;
            }

            return ($ch === FALSE) ? "" : $this->config("apps.flags.employee_generations.{$ch}.name");
        }
    }

    if($sample = new Sample()){
        for($age=19;$age<=71;$age++){
            $sample->employee_age = $age ;
            printf("%s,%s\n",$age,$sample->Check());
        }
    }
```